# Orthogonal set and linear independence and proofs.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Could you help me with this, this is in all likelihood a duplicate question but the matter is not about the solution it is about if my solution is correct, whenever I am proving something in Linear Algebra, I always have this feeling that either my proof is incorrect or a more sophisticated proof exists.

For example, take the question given a set of orthonormal vectors $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ prove that they are linearly independent.

My proof -Let them be linearly dependent and orthogonal, then $\langle x_i, x_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$, and  $a_1x_1 +\dots + a_n x_n =0$ where not all the $a_i$ are zero.

Then  $$(-a_1/a_j) x_1+\dots+(-a_{j-1}/a_j) x_{j-1} +(-a_{j+1}/a_j)a_{j+1} +\dots+(-a_n/a_j)x_n = x_j.$$
Now $$\langle x_j, x_n\rangle =(-a_1/a_j) \langle x_1,x_n\rangle +\dots+(-a_n/a_j)\langle x_j, x_n\rangle = -a_n/a_j,$$ this set is independent.

My question, is this proof incorrect/more sophisticated proofs exist? and how do I master proofs in general?

Comment: I have edited it (i) to make it legible (ii) to state the correct definition of "linearly independent". As to your proof it is defective because (i) you may have divided by $0$ (ii)   the set of numbers is Not independent. You should not be looking for sophisticated proofs, but rather simple proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(V, <•, •>) $ be a inner product space.

Suppose, $S= \{e_1 ,e_2,...,e_n\}$ be a orthonormal set of vectors in $V$.

Claim: $S\subset V$ Linearly independent.

To prove a set of vectors is linearly independent we have to show that the zero vector can be written as a unique linear combination of the vectors in the set. (No non trivial combination exists)

Let,$$ 0=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k e_k$$

\begin{align} 0=||\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k e_k||^2 &=<
\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k e_k,\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k e_k>\\ &=
    \sum_{k=0}^{n} |c_k|^2 \end{align}

Hence, $c_k =0   \space \space  \forall k\in {\mathbb{N}_n}$